# How to deserialize this json in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
  [
      "news",
      "{\"marketType\":\"chako\",\"data\":\"[{\\\"price\\\":572.05,\\\"qty\\\":106},{\\\"price\\\":224.08,\\\"qty\\\":700.25},{\\\"price\\\":440.5,\\\"qty\\\":600.55}]\"}"
        ]
```

I am getting this data in a chrome via websocket. This actually starts with 42 but I have removed it for simplicity as it can be removed by `String.split("42",2)`. Tried custom deserializer and other things but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's an array, where the second element is a string containing JSON, which has 2 fields, `marketType` and `data`. `data` is again, a string containing JSON.

EDITED: Java solution

```java
    void test() throws IOException {
        String json = "["
            + "\"news\","
            + " \"{\\\"marketType\\\":\\\"chako\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"[{\\\\\\\"price\\\\\\\":572.05,\\\\\\\"qty\\\\\\\":106},{\\\\\\\"price\\\\\\\":224.08,\\\\\\\"qty\\\\\\\":700.25},{\\\\\\\"price\\\\\\\":440.5,\\\\\\\"qty\\\\\\\":600.55}]\\\"}\""
            + "]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<String> arr = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
        Map<String, String> obj = mapper.readValue(arr.get(1), new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});

        List<Map<String, Number>> data = mapper.readValue(obj.get("data"), new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Number>>>() {});

        System.out.println(data);
    }
```

BEFORE EDIT:

JavaScript solution for use in chrome.

```js
const arr =   [
      "news",
      "{\"marketType\":\"chako\",\"data\":\"[{\\\"price\\\":572.05,\\\"dairy\\\":106},{\\\"price\\\":224.08,\\\"dairy\\\":700.25},{\\\"price\\\":440.5,\\\"dairy\\\":600.55}]\"}"
        ];
const record = JSON.parse(arr[1]);
const data = JSON.parse(record["data"])
console.log(data) // This is an array or objects with "price" and "dairy" properties
```

Comment: Thanks but this is in JS. I am trying this in Java with Jackson

Answer (score 0):

So this is a slightly messed up bit of stringified data. To unstringify or parse this data you will need to use JSON.parse on the object and each property. it you will need to first isolate the second part of the array. Then parse the data object in the object. Essentially you have sub properties that are double stringified. If you have control over the other end I might suggest you fix the bug that's causing you to stringify properties of the object.

```
let array = [
      "news",
      "{\"marketType\":\"chako\",\"data\":\"[{\\\"price\\\":572.05,\\\"qty\\\":106},{\\\"price\\\":224.08,\\\"qty\\\":700.25},{\\\"price\\\":440.5,\\\"qty\\\":600.55}]\"}"
        ];
let object = JSON.parse(array[1]);
object.data = JSON.parse(data);
```

if for some reason you have multiple stringified sub properties like this you may need to use object.keys and create a recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`

`Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);`